# How to set the minimum Metaspace in Java 8

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, java-8

I have the problem, that the default Metaspace size is too small.

Right after the startup of my (Tomcat and Spring based) web application, there is a major collection, because the Metaspace is exhausted. Before Java 8, I could set the initial PermGen size with `-XX:PermSize`. Now, I'm searching for a Java 8 equivalent for that, but I had no luck so far. I'm using the G1 garbage collector.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To set the meta space to 100M, use `-XX:MetaspaceSize=100M`. 
https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/about_g1_garbage_collector_permanent

Comment: Even though this setting solved the issue, there is a slight misconception, let me clarify that. MetaspaceSize does not increase the Metaspace size, what it does is "telling" the JVM the Metaspace size threshold after which a full GC is triggered.